# Wait and update the result from RESTful service in an android SDK

Tags: android

I am crating a SDK which has a Json call. The result of it is either a error number or success number. The SDK is working fine and I am getting expect result. But the issue is when I use that SDK with the app, I am unable to wait till the whole connection process is completed.

Error e = myApi.activate(getActivationCode());

What is the best way to implement a proper wait and result in both SDK and Android application.

Comment: There is tons of ways do that. I am using [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: Do I have to implement in SDK or the App?

Answer (score 0):

I have used simple interface to solve that problem. This also gives more freedom for the person using the SDK to play with UI